# Apply custom masterpage to all SP Foundation sites

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom masterpage which is been deployed as a feature. I am using SP foundation not SP Server.

I have activated the feature however the masterpage has only been applied to the top level sites. Can someone please let me know what ive done wrong with my event receiver.

```
   public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        if (siteCollection != null)
        {
            SPWeb topLevelSite = siteCollection.RootWeb;

            // Calculate relative path to site from Web Application root.
            string WebAppRelativePath = topLevelSite.ServerRelativeUrl;
            if (!WebAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                WebAppRelativePath += "/";
            }

            // Enumerate through each site and apply branding.
            foreach (SPWeb site in siteCollection.AllWebs)
            {
                site.MasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
                site.CustomMasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
                site.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great!